# Is it possible to do this <ComponentName {...this.state.values.map} /> and how (reactjs)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do this to a component but it seems that I'm doing something wrong. I'm pulling an array of objects from an API

```
<ComponentName {...this.state.values.map} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to name the property:

```
<ComponentName propName={this.state.values} />
```

(i think `this.state.values` is `array` of `object`)

In ComponentName constructor:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  console.log(props.propName);
}
```